# Hierarchy table in power bi

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I have a table as below:

| Org1 | Org2 | Dept1 | Dept2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | O2 | Dept1.1 | Dept2.1 |
| O1 | O3 | Dept1.2 | Dept2.2 |
| O2 |  | Dept1.3 | Dept2.3 |
| O1 | O2 | Dept1.4 | Dept2.4 |
| O1 |  | Dept1.5 | Dept2.5 |

Based on that, I need a graph (table/matrix) in Power BI as below:

| O1 | O2 | O3 |
| --- | --- | --- |

| Dept1 | Dept2 | Dept1 | Dept2 | Dept1 | Dept2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dept1.1 | Dept2.1 | Dept1.1 | Dept2.1 | Dept1.2 | Dept2.2 |
| Dept1.2 | Dept2.2 | Dept1.3 | Dept2.3 |  |  |
| Dept1.4 | Dept2.4 | Dept1.4 | Dept2.4 |  |  |
| Dept1.5 | Dept2.5 |  |  |  |  |

The graph combines the ORG1 and ORG2 columns into top layer of the final table and Dept1 and Dept2 columns under this layer. All values in column Dept1 and Dept2 will be placed under 6 columns.

Any quick help on the best approach to that would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me how to interpret the original table structure and what the rules are for the transformation.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I improved the question to reduce misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to work with if you reshape your data by unpivoting the first two and last two columns (and add a column for the subdept index) to get

| OrgCol | Org | Dept | SubDept | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT1 | Dept1.1 | 1 |
| ORG2 | O2 | DEPT1 | Dept1.1 | 1 |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT2 | Dept2.1 | 1 |
| ORG2 | O2 | DEPT2 | Dept2.1 | 1 |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT1 | Dept1.2 | 2 |
| ORG2 | O3 | DEPT1 | Dept1.2 | 2 |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT2 | Dept2.2 | 2 |
| ORG2 | O3 | DEPT2 | Dept2.2 | 2 |
| ORG1 | O2 | DEPT1 | Dept1.3 | 3 |
| ORG1 | O2 | DEPT2 | Dept2.3 | 3 |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT1 | Dept1.4 | 4 |
| ORG2 | O2 | DEPT1 | Dept1.4 | 4 |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT2 | Dept2.4 | 4 |
| ORG2 | O2 | DEPT2 | Dept2.4 | 4 |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT1 | Dept1.5 | 5 |
| ORG1 | O1 | DEPT2 | Dept2.5 | 5 |

With the data format, it's much easier to create a matrix visual like you want:

[image: Matrix Visual]

For the Values field, I used a simple measure:

```
Department = SELECTEDVALUE ( OrgDepts[SubDept] )
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexisOlson. This was my first intention. But as I have O1 and O2 only in power bi not query editor, I could not do the unpivoting. Is there any way that I can take the columns to query editor or the similar thing in power query?

Comment: I'd recommend constructing O1 and O2 in the query editor along the lines of however you constructed them in DAX. Power Query is much better suited to reshaping data, in general.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the quick answer and solution!!